# rel=publisher for Google Plus and rel=me togheter?

Tags: google-plus, publisher, popularity

i don't know if is a mistake to put in the head, the link publisher

```
<link href="http://link-google+" rel="publisher"/>
```

but also `rel="me"`?

or i should to add it (rel="me") for example in my social button in the link for google plus ?

And is a mistake to have the link publisher in the head but for each pages of my website??

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english

Answer (score -1):

Our Google+ info are shown correct in a Google Search for "Cooper Webdesign" to https://www.cooper.dk, but what I find weird is that we havent linked the website to the Google+ account.

The "link/connect" context simply doesnt appear at "about" > "links" > "edit". And still, then it works fine. How can that be?